# AgentWork time fields

Tags: soap-api, fields

Does anybody knows if the fields ActiveTime,HandleTime from the object AgentWork Are in seconds?

Here is the documentation but it does not say anything about that.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_agentwork.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah it's in seconds. Here is the sample: [image]